# Count how many full stops a text file contains in Python

Tags: python, file, text, find

I would like to write a code that will read and open a text file and tell me how many "." (full stops) it contains

I have something like this but i don't know what to do now?!

```
f = open( "mustang.txt", "r" )
    a = []
    for line in f:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is absolutely no danger of your file being so large it will cause your computer to run out of memory (for instance, in a production environment where users can select arbitrary files, you may not wish to use this method):

```
f = open("mustang.txt", "r")
count = f.read().count('.')
f.close()
print count
```

More properly:

```
with open("mustang.txt", "r") as f:
    count = f.read().count('.')
print count
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('mustang.txt') as f:
    s = sum(line.count(".") for line in f)
```

Comment: That's a neat solution .. I like it better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like so:

```
with open('mustang.txt', 'r') as handle:
  count = handle.read().count('.')
```

If your file isn't too big, just load it into memory as a string and count the dots.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('mustang.txt') as f:
    fullstops = 0
    for line in f:
        fullstops += line.count('.')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
with open('mustangused.txt') as inf:
    count = 0
    for line in inf:
        count += line.count('.')

print 'found %d periods in file.' % count
```

Comment: What if a line contains more than one '.'?

Comment: Blender was the first and I was about 30 seconds after him. It's not a big deal, any of the existing answers will work for EatMyApples.

Comment: @Fraxtil ah ok .. thanks for letting me know, sometimes you rush for a solution (which then has a gap until someone points it out)

Answer (score 1):

even with Regular Expression

```
import re
with open('filename.txt','r') as f:
    c = re.findall('\.+',f.read())
    if c:print len(c)
```